# Is MDM Password History stored on device or on server?

Tags: iphone, ios, password, exchange-activesync, mdm

I was wondering if the password history is stored on the iOS device or on the server when the password history policy is implemented through MDM (specifically, Exchange ActiveSync)? I have done a lot of reading and while I would assume that it is stored on the device, I wanted to make sure. And if it is stored on the device, can anybody say how? Same with server? (I.e. hash/salt)

Comment: Sorry, doesn't answer your question… but, why is anyone still insisting on frequent p/w change in this day & age? It's well-known people just recycle badly obvious 'human' algorithms or write then down in plain sight.

Comment: OT: @Tetsujin- Our MDM (JAMF) forces the use of a complex password, and in conjunction with our passcode policies, also disallows reuse of old passwords. It is tied in with out Active Directory server, because it provides SSO to Google and other services that require credentials authorization. Some institutions, like my school, it is used equally for students at the low end to faculty and top-level administrators, who are required to use 2FA because of financial confidentiality, HIPAA and other high-security concerns. Famous and/or affluent families need tightened security.

Comment: Neither Microsoft nor the US & UK governments recommends enforced password changes any more. Refs: https://duo.com/decipher/microsoft-will-no-longer-recommend-forcing-periodic-password-changes and https://www.ncsc.gov.uk/collection/passwords/updating-your-approach